# How to make an argument array of strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, shell, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an `array x` of floating point numbers (of variable length `n`) which I want to pass to a shell script as command line arguments using `execl()`. I suppose I need to declare a pointer to a `char array **args[]` and then dynamically allocate this to have the length `n` and then do something like this:

```
 *args=malloc(n*sizeof(char[]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) sprintf( args[i] , "%f", x[i]);  
    execl("script.sh","script.sh", args, NULL);
```

However, I cannot get the allocation of args to work right. Could someone please hint at how this is done correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate room for both the array of character pointers, which is what you're going to pass to `execv()`, *and* the characters themselves. Note that you can't use `execl()` for this, you need to use the array-based ones, such as `execv()`.

```
char ** build_argv(const char *cmd, const float *x, size_t num)
{
  char **args, *put;
  size_t i;

  /* Allow at most 64 chars per argument. */
  args = malloc((2 + num) * sizeof *args + num * 64);
  args[0] = cmd;
  put = args + num; /* Initialize to first character after array. */
  for(i = 0; i < num; ++i)
  {
    args[1 + i] = put;
    put += snprintf(put, "%f", x[i]);
  }
  args[1 + num] = NULL; /* Terminate array. */
  return args;
}
```

The above should work, it builds a `NULL`-terminated array of strings. You can free the entire array (and the strings) with a single `free()` call.

Comment: Of course, but you are only allowed to accept an answer after 10 minutes :-)